# Add a permanent compiler option to g++

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, gcc, g++

I am using a g++ 4.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 to compile my c++ code, and it won't be compiled unless an -std=gnu++11 option is added to my command like this:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 main.cpp
```

Is there a way to add this option permanently to the compiler, because my text editor uses g++ to automatically compile my code and it won't work because I have to add this option and I can't add it like I can normally do inside of the terminal?

I've seen that people use some spec file to configure g++, but I don't understand how to do it, so the help from you guys will be appreciated.

Comment: Spec file? That might be [`make`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) with a [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29#Makefiles). A makefile is a horribly convoluted thing that I won't pretend to understand, though some people do, somehow.

Comment: @Bob: A Makefile is a rather simple thing that is easy to understand once you get the idea of it being functional, not procedural. It's also mighty helpful in any kind of development. I wrote a [tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile) about it which might be helpful for you...

Comment: @DevSolar Yea, I was kinda joking there. Personally, I've never had a reason to learn about them (IDEs! :D), but the people who bother can probably pick it up quite quickly.

Comment: Note that spec file and Makefile are almost completely unrelated things: while the former is a compiler configuration file usually shipped with your compiler, the latter is a build instruction file shipped with your project. For the latter, `export CXXFLAGS=-std=gnu++11` would usually suffice, but that's not the question at hand I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply create a shell script `~/bin/g++` containing the lines

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 "$@"
```

and ensure that `~/bin` is on the `PATH`, and listed there before any other directory which contains a `g++` executable (usually thats's `/usr/bin`). Editing the [spec files](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Spec-Files.html) is possible, but for your settings to become default, I believe you'd have to change the default specs, which means it will require root access and severe tinkering with the gcc internals. There is a good chance that this tinkering would be undone by the next upgrade of g++.

Comment: This also requires that `~/bin` first in `$PATH`, at least before the directory where the real g++ lives. I'd suggest `alias g++='g++ --std=gnu++11'` instead.

Comment: @ott, alias is all right for interactive command line use, but usually won't affect a command invoked by some editor, as OP requires.

Comment: Ok, from within an editor the script is the right way.

Comment: As @ott correctly pointed out, your dir has to come before the established ones. Edited the question. Also note that the `~` in my answer refers to your home directory, so you should write `export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}`. Putting personal stuff in `/bin` is a bad idea, and should have required root access which my answer claims to be unneccessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 10 and want to use `g++ -std=c++17 <filename>` to compile the C++ file by default C++17 Standard, you can simply create a bash(shell) script and can name it `run.sh`.

The content of file `run.sh` as suggested by @MvG:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec g++ -std=gnu++17 "$@"
```

Now in the command line type

```
./run.sh <filename>
```

and it should be compiled :)

Note: You may have to install git (bash) in Windows and add it to PATH (this can be easily done by adding the path to bin folder in the installed git folder in the system environment variable) .